# Dual GPU and ubuntu, can it be?

Tags: video

Hello Linux / UBUNTU world!
i just have a question that im sure has been asked / seeked before!

I have a desktop with

Dual Nvidia 8800GT's

I use 3 of the 4 DVI ports

2 smaller screens and one large screen

is there a way to configure these to work like they would in windows?
IE drag stuff from one to the other, pop a window in one and one in the other etc.

Please tell me it can be done lol.

Answer (score 0):

Are you already using the Nvidia binary driver? If not, follow [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) to get it installed. [This guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaMultiMonitors) about Nvidia and multi-monitors is a bit old but should still be useful. Once you have the Nvidia binary driver installed, you should be able to find an Nvidia configuration utility that will allow you to setup the monitors in a span.

I must warn you, however, that this is not likely to be easy to setup. Linux, binary GPU drivers, and multi-monitors are often a pain. Throw in dual GPUs and you've got the makings of high blood-pressure disorder.

Comment: Whilst the links may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.